# Jackson JSON Deserialization: array elements in each line

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) and would like to pretty-print JSON such that each element in arrays goes to each line, like:

```
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "blah" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Setting `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` true only inserts newline characters for object fields, not array elements, printing the object in this way instead:

```
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "blah" : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could extend the [DefaultPrettyPrinter](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.html) and override the methods *beforeArrayValues(…)* and *writeArrayValueSeparator(…)* to archieve the desired behaviour. Afterwards you have to add your new Implementation to your JsonGenerator via [*setPrettyPrinter(…)*](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#setPrettyPrinter%28com.fasterxml.jackson.core.PrettyPrinter%29).

Answer (score 36):

If you don't want to extend `DefaultPrettyPrinter` you can also just set the `indentArraysWith` property externally:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

DefaultPrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
prettyPrinter.indentArraysWith(DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE);

String json = objectMapper.writer(prettyPrinter).writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: Lf2SpacesIndenter is deprecated (and gone in newer versions); Use DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE

Comment: Worked for me with DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE. This answer provides an easier solution.

Comment: This comment is the right answer.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to the helpful hints, I was able to configure my `ObjectMapper` with desired indentation as follows:

```java
private static class PrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {
    public static final PrettyPrinter instance = new PrettyPrinter();

    public PrettyPrinter() {
        _arrayIndenter = Lf2SpacesIndenter.instance;
    }
}

private static class Factory extends JsonFactory {
    @Override
    protected JsonGenerator _createGenerator(Writer out, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return super._createGenerator(out, ctxt).setPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter.instance);
    }
}

{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new Factory());
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Mapper can be configured (jackson-2.6) with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ...
DefaultPrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
prettyPrinter.indentArraysWith(DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE);
mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(prettyPrinter);

//use mapper
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14939762/1091453) thankfully provided by OP shows a way for obtain a single-array-element-per-line formatted JSON  `String` from `writeValueAsString`. Based on it here a solution to write the same formatted JSON directly to a file with `writeValue` with less code:

```java
private static class PrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {
    public static final PrettyPrinter instance = new PrettyPrinter();

    public PrettyPrinter() {
        _arrayIndenter = Lf2SpacesIndenter.instance;
    }
}

{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(PrettyPrinter.instance);
    writer.writeValue(destFile, objectToSerialize);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try out JSON Generator...

[API Reference](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator.html) 
[good example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/)