# How to make com.fasterxml.jackson print array vertically?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having issue trying to print array in Jackson vertically. I managed to get it to pretty print, but is there a way to print array vertically? (see the result section below, list of friends Anne and Bill)

I know in this example it's very simple, but in my real code the array can be more than a hundred, which will be better to show it vertically.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
public class TestJackson{
  public void testJackson() throws JsonProcessingException{
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        MyClass myPojo = new MyClass();
        String report = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo);
        System.out.println(report);
    }
}
```

My Pojo:

```
class MyClass{
    private String name="John";
    private List<String> friends = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Address homeAddress = new Address("20", "Main St.");
    private Address workAddress = new Address("11", "Corner St.");
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public List<String> getFriends(){
        if (friends.size() == 0) {
            friends.add("Anne");
            friends.add("Bill");
        }
        return friends;
    }
    public Address getHomeAddress(){
        return homeAddress;
    }
    public Address getWorkAddress(){
        return workAddress;
    }
}
class Address{
    private String no;
    private String street;
    
    public Address(String no, String street){
        this.no = no;
        this.street = street;
    }
    
    public String getNo(){
        return no;
    }
    public String getStreet(){
        return street;
    }
    
}
```

My Result:

```
  "name" : "John",
  "friends" : [ "Anne", "Bill" ],
  "homeAddress" : {
    "no" : "20",
    "street" : "Main St."
  },
  "workAddress" : {
    "no" : "11",
    "street" : "Corner St."
  }
}
```

Comment: See also: [Jackson JSON Deserialization: array elements in each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938667/jackson-json-deserialization-array-elements-in-each-line)

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober .Works!