# fasterxml.jackson ObjectMapper's prettyPrint uses \r\n instead of \n

Tags: java

When running on windows I always get "\r\n" in the output, but I was trying to just return "\n"

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
return objectMapper.readTree("{\"key\":\"value\"}")
    .toPrettyString();
```

Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I seem to recall -- and this could be outdated -- that several of the libraries decided to be "helpful" and use the system defined line ending. It might be possible to set the `DefaultIndenter` to a specific line feed. See, perhaps, [Configure line endings](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/585).

Comment: call setDefaultPrettyPrinter with an instance of PrettyPrinter that does what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938984/829571